# How to create 3 image full size boxes responsive

Tags: html, responsive

my question is how to create 3 image full size linkable boxes responsive

[image: https://imgur.com/a/RfruG]

Please advise, what framework to use?

Comment: do you want to put text or something else on the images?

Comment: Hi, only hover to this images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally don't do your work here but I made an exception and hope this is your solution:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

body>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

body>div>h1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

@media (max-device-width: 20cm) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  body>div {
    height: 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image:url(https://loremflickr.com/300/200)">
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div style="background-image:url(https://loremflickr.com/300/200)">
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div style="background-image:url(https://loremflickr.com/300/200)">
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and it is responsive?

Comment: It works for every display-ratio, so if you mean that: yes

Comment: edited it, now it switches directions at a specific device-width

Comment: “I need someone like this”... darn... he IS just trying to get his work done for him. Delete this post please. Let’s not encourage others.

Comment: @patrick I know, but he can't get any further if he doesn't learn to do it by himself

Comment: Ok, it works ,but only in Google Chrome / its there a bug with Firefox and Safari

Comment: I used `cm` in the media queries, but apperantly this is not supported everywhere. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution

Comment: the solution is px?

Comment: you could set it to whatever fits best for you

Comment: ok, in chrome works fine standard and responsive too, but in firefox,safari - please check : http://bodyproof.eu/angel/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167282/discussion-between-sebastian-speitel-and-thomas-d).

Answer (score 0):

For a setup as straightforward as this, you can give each image a percentage width of `33.33%`.

```css
div {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
line-height: 180px;
}

img {
float: left;
width: 33.33%;
height: 180px;
}

img:nth-of-type(1) {
background-color: rgb(127, 0, 0);
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
background-color: rgb(127, 127, 0);
}

img:nth-of-type(3) {
background-color: rgb(0, 63, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box">
<img src="" alt="Image 1" />
<img src="" alt="Image 2" />
<img src="" alt="Image 3" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use col-md-4 property of bootstrap for responsive part and insert the desired link in the link tag.
I hope it will help you.